# Observable do not call onComplete (sqlbrite - mapToOneOrDefault)

Tags: database, rx-java, rx-java2, sqlbrite

I have select from sqlbrite db but observable do not call onComplete for some reason.

My code:

```
fun BriteDatabase.selectDayTimelineRecord(dayTimestamp: Long) =
createQuery(table_timeline, selectWDayRecords(dayTimestamp)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .mapToOneOrDefault(StatItem(dayTimestamp, 0)) { cursor -> cursor.mapTimelineStat() }
```

and then I try variants:

1. working but I need to keep order so I can not use flatmap

   Observable.fromIterable(0..6).flatMap{
       db.selectDayTimelineRecords(timestampOfDayInWeek(it))
   }.buffer(7).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {}
2. not working (not delivery result but I do not know why)

   Observable.fromIterable(0..6).concatMap{
       db.selectDayTimelineRecords(timestampOfDayInWeek(it))
   }.buffer(7).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {}

As result I want Observable with list of T...

Anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with SQLBrite but `createQuery` supposed to be keep notifying database changes. If you want to get value just once then you can use `take()` operator.

```
fun BriteDatabase.selectDayTimelineRecord(dayTimestamp: Long) =
    createQuery(table_timeline, selectWDayRecords(dayTimestamp))
        .mapToOneOrDefault(StatItem(dayTimestamp, 0)) { cursor -> cursor.mapTimelineStat() }
        .take(1)
```

Then your `concatMap` implementation will work.